# Align components in TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

First of all, all of my components have to be created at runtime. Well, I've got a `TableLayout` and inside this table view a bunch of `TableRow`. Inside every `TableRow`, there should be:

- a `Button` at the right side having a given fixed height and a given fixed width
- a `TextView` that fills the "rest" of the `TableRow` being allowed to wrap its text

The height of the `TableRow` should be the max of the `Button` height and the `TableRow` height. I either fail to set the `Button` height or only one of the elements (`TableRow` or `Button`) is displayed.

Maybe somebody could help me.

My current code:

```
    // fetching the table layout
    final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ShoppingListTableLayout);
    tl.removeAllViews();

    // creating a single layout for every component
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 1, 0, 1);

    TableRow.LayoutParams bParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(m_Resources
        .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ButtonWidth), m_DefaultButtonHeight_px);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Iterator<xy> itr = ...

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      final xy = itr.next();
      final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
      tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

      // 1. Child: TextView
      final TextView CurrTxtView = new TextView(this);
      CurrTxtView.setPadding(TV_PADDING_PX, TV_PADDING_PX, TV_PADDING_PX, TV_PADDING_PX);
      CurrTxtView.setTextSize(TV_TEXT_SIZE);
      CurrTxtView.setTypeface(m_Font);
      CurrTxtView.setTextColor(TEXT_ACTIVE_COLOR);
      CurrTxtView.setText(CurrItem.GetName());
      CurrTxtView.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
      tr.addView(CurrTxtView, CHILD_INDEX_TV);

      // 2. Child Button ("Edit" für aktive, "Delete" für inaktive)
      final Button MyButton = new Button(this);
      MyButton.setTextColor(TEXT_ACTIVE_COLOR;
      MyButton.setText(m_Resources.getString(CurrItem.GetIsActive() ? R.string.EditString
          : R.string.DeleteString));
      MyButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);
      MyButton.setTypeface(m_Font);
      MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {... }
      });

      tr.addView(MyButton, CHILD_INDEX_B);

      tr.setPadding(m_TableRowPadding_px, 0, m_TableRowPadding_px, 0);
      tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

tl.addView(tr, 0);
    }
```

In this case only the buttons are displayed and even worse on the left side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you add the `TextView` and `Button` at the right indexes(`CHILD_INDEX_TV` and `CHILD_INDEX_B` are `0` and `1`, although you could just drop them and just add the views in the correct order) a bad thing in your layout is the `LayoutParams` that you set to the `TextView`, the view that doesn't show up:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

First of all, the `TextView` is the child of a `TableRow` so you should set the `TableRow.LayoutParams` and not `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, secondly I don't understand why you suddenly decided to leave the `TableLayout.LayoutParams` and go for the `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` for the view's height. In the end it should be:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams tvParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

To push the `Button` to the right you could simply stretch the column with the `TextView` by using:

```
tl.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
```

Comment: Well, honestly, I don't understand either, what I did. And I still do not understand this whole layout stuff.
But anyway, thank you for your answer, it works perfectly! :)